# Windows 11 Enterprise asking for UAC when copying my files into my own Documents folder

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems, windows-11, uac

I think my filesystem killed itself last night. Today, I was cleaning up my desktop, and started getting UAC prompts when copying files owned by my user from my desktop folder to my documents folder. Which.... is not right. I tried taking ownership of my home directory via the security dialog and takeown.exe and both failed - security dialogue would not recognize my user because it's an AAD user and apparently the security dialogue can only handle domain and local users. Running takeown on my home dir as admin in powershell gave a simple "Access Denied." Also, if I authorize the UAC prompt to do the copy/move, often Windows then cannot find the source files anymore, like it crossed some kind of permission barrier, with the source on one side and the destination on the other. Other than setting my laptop on fire, what can I do to restore my proper ownership of my own files?

Comment: Given that you're in an AzureAD, I assume you contacted your system administrators and checked with them first, just to ensure they haven't revoked permissions etc?